# Angular- How to close snackbar on 401 error?

Tags: angular, http-status-code-401, android-snackbar

I am using snackbar to show error messages. There is auth-interceptor.ts file in my code, where i'm checking for 401 error and redirecting to login page in this particular case. 
My code is,

```
return next.handle(authReq).do(event => { }, err => {
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
    this.router.navigate(['logout']);
  }
});
```

Can i put any logic in this file, so i can close snackbar from any component.

Comment: where is snackbar code?

Comment: Its shown in multiple components where api call giving error response.

Comment: so send some flag along with error response in corresponding components in order to check whether to show snack bar or not